# Reverse directions of spacemouse

Tags: interface, customization

I tried Blender today but my [Spacemouse](http://www.3dconnexion.com/products/spacenavigator.html) operated in reverse direction. Where can I change this setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adjusting mouse settings in *User preferences > Input* (You can open the user preferences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, or *File > User preferences*:

[image]

- *Invert Wheel Zoom Direction* inverts the zoom direction when using the mouse wheel in the 3D view.
- *Invert Zoom Direction* inverts the zoom direction when zooming by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>MMB</kbd>.

You could also try the solution posted in this thread on [Blender Artists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?246999-2-62-and-3DConnexion-SpaceNavigator-Can-Axes-be-Inverted):

> RESOLVED: I received an answer to this question from Tehrasha in the
>   Blender.org forum.
>
> Tehrasha pointed out that one of the buttons on the 3D mouse displays
>   a settings menu with options to invert the axes.
>
> This works for me. The only thing on my wish list now is to remove the
>   need to hold down SHIFT for panning actions, as this breaks the smooth
>   flying effect of the 3D mouse (it interrupts any rotation). It's odd
>   that zoom (forward / back) works regardless of SHIFT state.

Comment: Clicking the left button of the spacemouse showed a nice menu letting me invert all axes. Ty sir!

Comment: The ~nice menu~ turned out to be the the driver in some kind of mini-mode when not started. Guess I'll just save a profile for Blender.

Comment: Benefitted from becoming aware of this use preferences side panel with its own settings using the trackpad on a 10.13.6 macOS and I wanted Natural Trackpad Direction.  Seems you have to manually make it match the OS setting.

Answer (score 0):

For 3D Connexion MouseSpace and Blender 3.1.

**Configuration menu**

Use the left switch:

[image]

This panel is displayed:

[image]

There are two important settings, axis direction and axis allocation.

**Invert axis direction**

`Invert Axis Pan/Orbit` switches are used to change the sign of the joystick input to pan and rotate the camera.

The natural way is when the switches are not selected: Pushing the joystick right or turning it clockwise exposes things on the right and hide things on the left.

[image]

Selecting the switches is what make the axes feeling "inverted", it seems to be the default configuration.

Instead of moving the center of the view field, the joystick moves what is visible, e.g. rotating clockwise moves the image to the right, so a portion of the image on the right is hidden and a new portion appears on the left of the field of view. That's like piloting a plane with the stick inverted.

**Choose how height is controlled**

`Swap Y and Z Axes` controls which mouse axis is used for Blender Z axis, e.g. to pan/dolly the camera up/down, that is to change its height or the height of the viewport center.

Without this option selected, Z is controlled by moving the joystick up/down which seems logical but is a bit difficult to coordinate with another axis.

When selected, height is controlled by moving the joystick forward/backward which may seem more natural in the end as this allows to control the camera displacement in the screen plane by using axes in the same mouse plane (horizontal plane).

Swapping Y and Z consequence is to change the Y axis control too. Y axis for the camera means dollying back/forward (which in Blender is used to zoom, while a true zoom would be to change the focal length).